# If $X$ is a LCHS and $f \in C_{C}(X)$ and $\mu$ is a Borel measure, then $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I want to prove the following statement:

> If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff topological space, and $f \in C_{C}(X)$ ($f$ is a continuous function with compact support), and if $\mu$ is a Borel measure (i.e., $\mu(K) < \infty$ for $K^{\text{ cpt}} \subseteq X$), then $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$.

My professor gave a proof of this in class, but his proof is missing some details that I filled in.  I am hoping all of the details are correct.

Suppose $f \in C_{C}(X)$ ($f$ has codomain $\mathbb{C}$).  We want to prove $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$, i.e., $\int \limits_{X} |f| \,d\mu < \infty$.

Note that since $f \in C_{C}(X)$, we know $|f| \in C_{C}(X)$.  This is because if $f$ is continuous, so is $|f|$ (proved by using the fact that $||f(x)| - |f(y)|| < |f(x) - f(y)|$).  Since $|f|$ is continuous, it is Borel measurable, and so it can be integrated.

Furthermore, $\{x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} = \{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \} \implies \overline{\{x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \}} = \overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}$.  Thus, since $\overline{\{x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \}}$ is compact, so is $\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}$.

Now that we have $|f|$ is in $C_{C}(X)$, notice that $|f(x)| = |f(x)| \chi_{\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}}$ for all $x \in X$.  This shows that $\int \limits_{X} |f(x)| \,d\mu = \int \limits_{X} |f(x)|\chi_{\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}} \,d\mu = \int \limits_{\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}} |f(x)| \,d\mu$.

Finally, since $|f(x)|$ is continuous everywhere (and, namely, on the compact set $\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}$), we know it attains a maximum.  Let $M$ be the maximum of $|f|$ over this compact set.  Then we have:

$\int \limits_{\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}} |f(x)| \,d\mu < \int \limits_{\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}} M \,d\mu = M\mu(\overline{\{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \}}) < \infty$ since $\mu$ is a Borel measure and so the measure of any compact set is finite.

I think all of the details are sound (except for the fact that I used the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity and instead should have proved the preimage of open sets under $|f|$ are open...).

Comment: Nice proof (although a bit pedantic :) ) Two remarks: 1) In the last equation, the first $<$ has to be a $\leq$. 2) You can also show continuity of $|f|$ more easily (without $\varepsilon$-$\delta$) by noting that $|f| = |\cdot| \circ f$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for your input!  At the level I am at, I need all of the detail I can get, or else my mind casts doubt on every step.  Seriously!  That's why I spell out every step in (seemingly unnecessary) detail.  By the way, I forgot to mention in the proof that $\overline{\{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} }$ is a measurable set because its complement is open, so it is in $\mathcal{B}(X)$.