# Borel measure and positive linear forms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm just starting to learn about positive linear forms.  If we call $C_{C}(X)$ the space of all continuous functions with compact support from domain $X$ and $\mathbb{C}$ (with $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff topological space), then we can define a positive linear form:

> $\Lambda: C_{C}(X) \to \mathbb{C}$  by $\Lambda(f) = \int \limits_{X} f \,d\mu$ where $\mu$ is a Borel measure (i.e., $\mu(K) < \infty$ for any measurable, compact set $K$ in $X$).

So, my professor said that this implies any Borel measure gives a positive linear form via integration.

**My question is:  Why do we make the distinction that the measure has to be a Borel measure?  Don't we get a positive linear form no matter what positive measure we integrate against?  Why does it have to be a Borel measure?**

I feel like there is some intuition I am missing here that I am hoping someone can help me understand.  The linearity of the integral holds regardless of if the measure is a Borel measure or not.

Special note:  Just before this statement, we proved that if $f \in C_{C}(X)$ and $\mu$ is a Borel measure, then $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$.  I'm not sure if that has any special significance here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The functions must be measurable. Continuous functions are measurable if you use a $\sigma$-algebra which includes the open sets. Using a Borel measure is then the least restrictive condition that you need. You can add more sets to the $\sigma$-algebra if you want, but you need at least Borel.

Comment: @T.A.E. I'm not really sure why using a Borel measure is the "least restrictive condition that you need."  I now understand from what you said that to make our functions measurable, our $\sigma$-algebra will need to include the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  But then why does the measure have to be Borel (i.e., why do we need that the measure of each compact set is finite?)?

Comment: The important property which you want is that all $C_c$-functions have to be integrable w.r.t. $\mu$. There are two conditions we need here: 1) Each $f \in C_c$ has to be measurable. For this, it suffices if all open sets are measurable. 2) You need integrability. In your post in which you showed that every $C_c$ function is integrable (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918378/), a crucial property that you used was that the measure of compact sets is finite (check that!). Hence, we require that the measure of compact sets is finite.

Comment: BTW: The language that you are using is not standard usage. Ordinarily, a **Borel measure** is any measure defined on (at least) the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If each compact set is of finite measure, this is called a locally finite measure or something like that.

Comment: @user46944 - PhoemueX explained things fairly well. You do need $\Lambda(f)$ to be defined and finite in order to have a linear form on $C_{c}(X)$. Requiring the Borel measures to be finite on compact sets does the job. The assumptions are minimal in order to work in this setting.

Comment: @T.A.E. Why do we need it to be finite?  Once I understand why we need it to be finite, your explanations will make perfect sense to me.  Is it because the codomain of $\Lambda$ is $\mathbb{C}$, and thus for the function to be defined, its value better be finite/a complex number?

Comment: @PhoemueX I didn't know how to tag more than one person in my last post.

Comment: @user46944 Yes, that is the reason. The term "functional" usually means with values in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$, i.e. the integral has to be finite-valued.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for your clear and helpful answers!  Now, how do I close this question?  I want to keep it around so that I can reference it in the future.